# EF Mapping: Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION

Tags: c#, entity-framework

**What I am trying to accomplish:**
I basically want an NWatchNode to have a collection of relations.
Then, each relation should have a single Node, a single RelatedNode, and a RelationType.

**Here is the error message I am receiving:**

> Unable to create instance of class NWatch.Entities.Test.NWatchTagTest.
>   Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Introducing FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint 'FK_dbo.NWatchRelations_dbo.NWatchNodes_RelatedNodeId' on
>   table 'NWatchRelations' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.
>   Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other
>   FOREIGN KEY constraints.

What am I doing wrong here, or how do I properly map this?

Here are my mappings:

```
// NWatchRelation
            modelBuilder.Entity<NWatchRelation>().Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("NWatchRelations");
            });
            modelBuilder.Entity<NWatchRelation>()
                .HasKey(t => t.Id)
                .Property(t => t.Id)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            modelBuilder.Entity<NWatchRelation>().HasRequired(t => t.Node).
                WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => t.NodeId).WillCascadeOnDelete();
            modelBuilder.Entity<NWatchRelation>().HasRequired(t => t.RelatedNode).
                WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => t.RelatedNodeId).WillCascadeOnDelete();

// NWatchNode
            modelBuilder.Entity<NWatchNode>().Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapInheritedProperties();
                m.ToTable("NWatchNodes");
            });
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new NWatchObjectBaseConfiguration<NWatchNode>());
            modelBuilder.Entity<NWatchNode>().HasKey(t => t.Id).
                Property(t => t.Id).
                HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
            modelBuilder.Entity<NWatchNode>().HasRequired(t => t.NodeTypeEntity).
                WithMany(t => t.Nodes).HasForeignKey(t => t.NodeTypeId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<NWatchNode>().HasMany(t => t.Tags).WithMany(t => t.Nodes);
            modelBuilder.Entity<NWatchNode>().HasMany(t => t.MonRequests).WithMany(t => t.Nodes);
            modelBuilder.Entity<NWatchNode>().HasMany(t => t.Relations);
            modelBuilder.Entity<NWatchNode>().Property(t => t.Location).IsOptional().HasMaxLength(100);
            modelBuilder.Entity<NWatchNode>().Ignore(t => t.SourceDefinitions);
            modelBuilder.Entity<NWatchNode>().Ignore(t => t.NodeType);
```

Comment: Remove `WillCascadeOnDelete` unless you plan on making use of that.